# How change the url query in the controller

Tags: yii, yii-components

I want to change the address of the page requested from the controller. 
For example: when prompted **site / edit** return **site/edit/12** 
where 12 - is a number of model. 
Of course I can use the redirect, but can be a way to do it is not use a redirect.
My snippet:

```
    public function actionEdit($id = null){
         if(!$id){
    $model = Portfolio::model()->createEmpty();
    $this->redirect('site/edit'.$model->id);// I think that redirect is bad
    Yii::app()->end();
      }
   // ... etc logic
     }
```

Comment: how you are generating random number 12? On each refresh / each call of edit action?

Comment: how do you reach the edit action without an id !!!?

Comment: To access the method without the identifier is the logic if not $id - on the model is created, and with it $id. In most cases $id need to find a record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionEdit($id = 0){
    if($id == 0){
       $this->redirect('/site/edit/12');
       exit();
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function actionEdit($id = 0){
    if($id == 0){
       $id = 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But redirect - is to re-initialize the application. I think that can be done without using a redirect.

Comment: Edited because your comment.

Comment: more simple, `actionEdit($id = 12)` but 12 is random number as per question.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with an  array :

```
$this->redirect(array('site/edit','id'=>$model->id));
```

if you want to hide the 'id' in your url, add a url rule in your config file.